# Prestashop - need module for generating visiting cards online

Tags: php, shopping-cart, prestashop

is there any module(without flash) available in Prestashop for generating visiting cards/ business cards online and then the user can add it to cart?

I am tired of searching for such Prestashop module.

Please help !!!

for ref. http://demo.onprintshop.com/product_design_customize.php?pid=1
But not in **flash** and as **Prestashop Module**

Answer (score 1):

Without flash, nope, there is not such module, as it is a customized module. It will be not as easy as flash based and will be very complex.

I dont think so if without flash there will be any, but it can be developed with some limitations.

Like you will have a defined set of design rules (backgrounds, colors, templates etc etc) which can be made manageable from admin. You can use JQuery (or any other ajax library) to make it more attractive.

It will be good if you still look into a flash solution.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I don't mind in designing such module with jQuery but then again the question arise of adding that customize product to the Prestashop shopping cart.

Comment: When it is a module, then during designing and development, it will be integrated into PS. It will require database tables, and some core database changes also like in the cart system and in the order processing.

Answer (score 0):

### My own experience

I created a photo-lab type site for a client some time ago using SWFUpload (a JavaScript + Flash uploader).

For the most part my app uses jQuery and I only used Flash for the upload because in 2010 FileAPI and FileReference weren't supported by major browsers so I couldn't upload files without refreshing the page (unless I used Flash or Java).

My implementation intended to allow users to add up-to 500 images in a batch. Each image would be individually configurable -- type of paper to print on, size of paper, red-eye-removal etc. some of which could affect the price, some couldn't.

### On the topic

What I can tell you is that implementing this in PrestaShop 1.3.1 required more than a module. The template was very dependent on the product/service-configuration module and we had to apply some core patches too (due to performance constraints we chose not to use PrestaShop's attribute system).

The business cards thing would require a bit less intrusion into the core behavior but still  you really shouldn't look for a module that can do this single-handedly because it's more complex then that.

The complexity on the user interface side is a bit bigger for your project than it was for mine, and it can be accomplished in jQuery, it just takes a bit more custom coding.